# set -e fails to catch all errors when output piped to awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to understand how error catching works when piped to `awk` in a bash script.  I have a bash script with :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e 
echo "hello"
OUTPUT=`ls /root/* | awk '{print $0}'`  
echo "world"
```

When I run this as a non-privileged user, the output is

```
hello
ls: cannot access /root/*: Permission denied
world
```

despite the fact that `set -e` should cause my script to end if *any* error occurs. The line `echo "world"` should not be executed because the script does generate an error.

Now if I replace the `awk` statement with `grep poo`, the script exits as expected.

QUESTION: What is `awk` doing that manages to hide the errors from bash?

Comment: `set -e` does not work the way you think it does. It **absolutely does not** promise to make all errors fatal. See the exercises below the allegory in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (though reading the allegory may have value too, if you're not allergic to walls of text; it provides a fairly good explanation of how we got here, and *why* `set -e` [has mutually-incompatible implementations](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) between different POSIX-family shells).

Comment: From the bash documentation: The shell does not exit if the command that fails is . . . any command in a pipeline but the last https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: That said, see `set -o pipefail` to make a failure at any point in a pipeline fatal -- but, bigger picture, I strongly suggest reconsidering your use of `set -e`.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely by definition; the output status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline.

You can trap this specific error in Awk explicitly:

```
ls /root/* | awk 'BEGIN {x=1} {x=0; print $NF } END { exit x }'
```

This causes Awk to set its exit status to reflect whether it received any input at all. This is similar to the `grep` behavior you discovered (report success if any matches were found).